# How to cancel process cURL download file in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have a case :

I use cURL in my localhost (with PHP) to download zip file from shared hosting. I have a problem. I want to stop the download when my download is still being processed. Is this possible to stop the download?

Cause, when I download the 300MB file size and in the middle of the process I reload my browser and access again with the same PHP script, so there are 2 in the Curl download process.

Is there a script to stop the download (stop cURL process download)?

It my code :

```
$path_download = "http://example.com/download/app.zip";
$target_download_file = "app.zip";

file_put_contents('progress.txt','');

$targetFile = fopen($target_download_file,'w');

$ch = curl_init($path_download);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,'progressCallback');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE,128);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,$targetFile);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($targetFile);

function progressCallback( $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size ){
    static $previousProgress = 0;
    if($download_size == 0)
        $progress = 0;
    else
        $progress = round($downloaded_size * 100 / $download_size);
    if ($progress > $previousProgress){
        $previousProgress = $progress;
        $fp = fopen('progress.txt','w');
        fputs($fp,"$progress");
        fclose( $fp );
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you doing here? You're downloading a file from one server to another server, and that download is triggered by a browser request, and if you load the script again it spawns a new downlad process? It seems to me that you approach might be wrong. You need to be able to reconnect the current download.